# Electron : Mac Icon is not working

Tags: icons, electron

I try to create the Mac .DMG for my application with the following command :

`electron-installer-dmg ./release-builds/automental-darwin-x64/automental.app Automental --out=release-builds --overwrite --icon=images/favicon.icns`

For me, there is nothing anormally and the path is ok and the icon too.
When, I'm launching the DMG file generated, I still have the default Mac Application icon and the desired icon is visible in a small file called *.VolumeIcon.icns*

So, am I doing something wrong ? Because I want to display my icons, not the default Mac one. (I already check : Node package are all up to date)

Comment: Is the `favicon.icns` inside `src` or do you have an `images` directory at the root?

Comment: No, I have a an ` images ` folder at the root of the project